# Does anyone know why Hagrid has fingers?

Tags: minifigures

Hagrid (hp061 and hp009) both have fingers instead of just the traditional c-cup hands.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: This has [been asked on the brickset forums](http://www.bricksetforum.com/discussion/755/hagrid-s-hands) but, without answer so far - let's hope someone finds some insight about this

Answer (score 2):

Since Hagrid is much larger than others, it is an opportunity to include slightly more detail without looking clumsy. The fingers might increase the illusion of being bigger.